# Tratamento de erro no node js

Tags: node.js, express.js

Estou fazendo um tratamento de erro que se for passado um id errado pela `url` ele retorna um *erro* **400**, mas quando eu faço o teste ele retorna um *erro* **200** mais uma mensagem

> `"error": "Error",
>   "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"5d69f4aa827b491c678c50a\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Product\""`

Segue o controller:

```
router.get('/product-view/:id', async (req, res) => {    
    const id = req.params.id    
    try{    
        if(!id) return res.status(404).send({ error: 'Produto não encontrado'})    
        console.log(id);        
        const product = await Product.findById(id);        
        res.send(product);        

    }catch(error){    
       res.send({    
            error: 'Error',
            message: error.message    
       })    
    }       
});
```

Comment: `Product.findById` pelo visto o erro é aqui ... você usa qual banco de dados?

Comment: eu uso o mongo DB

Comment: Status `200` não é de erro, mas sim de sucesso, tu precisa chamar o método `status` com o código de retorno. Ex. `res.status(400).send({error: 'Error', message: error.message})`

Answer (score 1):

***Problema:*** o `id` recuperado é um tipo diferente que o método `findById` entende, no caso esse método precisa de um [ObjectId](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids) (`mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`) para buscar a informação no banco [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb), ou um objeto com a seguinte estrutura `{_id: id}` ou uma `string` com o nome `_id`, [como está descrito na sua documentação](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

Particularmente falando eu prefiro sempre colocar um tipo que no caso é [ObjectId](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids), exemplo:

```js
router.get('/product-view/:id', async (req, res) => {    
    const id = req.params.id    
    try{    
        if(!id) return res.status(404).send({ error: 'Produto não encontrado'})    
        const _id = new ObjectId(id);  // instância requerida pelo seu código
        const product = await Product.findById({_id:_id}); // ou simplificando {_id}        
        res.send(product);        

    }catch(error){    
       res.send({    
            error: 'Error',
            message: error.message    
       })    
    }       
});
```

e esse tipo [ObjectId](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids) está `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` que é tipo de dado gravado no seu [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb).

ou solução rápida no seu código:

```js
router.get('/product-view/:id', async (req, res) => {    
    const id = req.params.id    
    try{    
        if(!id) return res.status(404).send({ error: 'Produto não encontrado'})      
        const product = await Product.findById({_id: id});        
        res.send(product);        

    }catch(error){    
       res.send({    
            error: 'Error',
            message: error.message    
       })    
    }       
});
```

<sup>***Referente:***</sup>

- [SchemaTypes](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)
- [SchemaTypes - ObjectId](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids)
- [Find By ID in Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/finding-documents.html)

<sup>***Exemplos***</sup>

- [Can't find documents searching by ObjectId using Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7882881/6797930)
- [mongoose find by ObjectId](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40756072/6797930)

Comment: Então usei o primeiro exemplo que voce colocou mas esta dando esse erro : ObjectId is not defined

Comment: Você precisa pegar o caminho completo, ai não é erro no meu código, e você precisa colocar a referencia correta, se está difícil faça a segunda opção, as duas estão corretas @EdgarSilva